# Every array[i] in interval

Tags: java, arrays

Input is array of ints, return true if all ints are either (1;5> or <5;10), else return false.

```
    public static boolean count(int[] array){
        if(10 >= int i : array && int i : array >= 5 || 0 <= int i : array &&  int i : array <= 5) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false; 
            break;
        }}
```

Expected output

```
    array[1,2,3,2,4] - true
    array[5,7,6,7,8] - true
    array[1,3,4,7,5] - false
```

I know the syntax of the condition is wrong, how can I make this?

Comment: read about for loops (you need one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the syntax of the for-loop for iterating over a array. If the condition fails, it will return immediately with `false` otherwise returns `true`.

```
public static boolean count(int[] array) {
 for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
   if(! <put you condition here>) {
       return false;
   } 
 }
 return true;
}
```

Note: `!` is negation symbol. It will do opposite of what you put in the if-condition.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason i thought it was super smart to use int i : array in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, I also improved the name of the method:

```
public static boolean allWithin1to5or5to10(int[] array) {
    return array.length != 0 && (allWithinRange(array, 1, 5) || allWithinRange(array, 5, 10));
}

public static boolean allWithinRange(int[] array, int min, int max) {
    for (int num : array) {
        if (!(min <= num && num <= max)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It passes these unit tests:

```
assertTrue(allWithin1to5or5to10(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 2, 4}));
assertTrue(allWithin1to5or5to10(new int[]{5, 7, 6, 7, 8}));
assertFalse(allWithin1to5or5to10(new int[]{1, 3, 4, 7, 5}));
```

Comment: Thank you, as I answered above, I thought that int i : array will automaticaly create a for cycle in if condition. And the "official name" isnt count, i'm writting it straight in here on iPad and count just happens to be the name that came in my mind 

Comment: I mean yours is offcourse more complete, but since all I needed was someone to tell me that int i : array cant be used to create for cycle in if condition, my deciding factor was the the fact that I've read the other one first.

Answer (score 0):

This another way for checking with int array.

```
public static boolean count(int[] array) {
  for(Integer arr: array){
    if(<Your condition>)
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Java 8 streams for this:

```
boolean oneToFive = IntStream.of(arr).allMatch(i -> (i >= 1 && i <= 5));
boolean fiveToTen = IntStream.of(arr).allMatch(i -> (i >= 5 && i <= 10));
boolean withinRange = oneToFive || fiveToTen;
```